# threading.join() not behaving as expected

Tags: python, multithreading

I need to build threads the perform a long running function as to not block my main thread.

I constructed a `for` to `start()` a thread, then `join()` that thread which should block the thread calling it (i.e. the one containing the `for`).

However, for some reason the following loop builds and starts each thread at the same time rather than after each `t1` has finished:

```
def myfunc()
    for _num in range(3):
        print "Hello"

for num in range(5):
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=myfunc)
    t1.start()
    t1.join()
    print "World"
```

What I expected:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
World
Hello
Hello
Hello
World...
```

What I get:

```
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
.
.
.
World
World
World
World
World
```

Comment: Maybe the output is being buffered. What if you run without buffering, or flush each print call?

Comment: I ran your code and it works exactly as you expect it to work, both Python 2.7 and 3.4.

Comment: @stovfl Why would moving `.join()` outside the `for` work? Without it, wont each of the 3 threads begin running in parallel?

Comment: @stovfl Of course my **expected** output is what I want. But moving '.join()` outside the loop does not do anything even close to it.

Comment: Can confirm it works as expected in Python 3.6 (Idle)